# Trying to port an iOS Native framework into NativeScript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, typescript, nativescript

Had written framework in SWIFT language and also created plugin for framework to port in NativeScript.But not able save APIKey in App Delegate life cycle methods and also unable to import the classes with the help of JavaScript or TypeScript language.Need some inputs on how to save APIKey and to import classes from framework into NativeScript.

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to save primitive data on iOS development you have to save them with Userdefaults. When you use userdefaults you can access data everywhere you want.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(25, forKey: "Age") // To save
UserDefaults.standart.value(forKey: "Age") as! Int // To read.
```